# retrieve route values from RouteTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routetable

i want retrieve route values from RouteTable, but it's null. can anybody help?

```
public static class GetRouteValues
{
    public static string GetSomeValue()
    {
        RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        var value = routes["somevalue"].ToString();
        return value;
    }
}
```

i want retrieve this value for using in global.asax file and set as default value for some routes value.

```
string value = GetRouteValues.GetSomeValue();
routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{_value}/home",
                        new
                        {
                            _value = value,
                            controller = "home",
                            action = "index"
                        });
```

Comment: What is `GetSomeValue()` supposed to do/return?

Comment: Are you trying to pull one of the values from the route in the current context or are you trying to pull out one of the globally defined routes.

Comment: @Jorn: This method retrun string value which should be retrieve from routes ///// @anthonyv: yes, i trying to pull from the route in the current context.

Comment: The whole route of just a value from the current route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok if you are trying to get the current route, you can do this from within a controller....

```
var completeRoute = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route;
//or
var justValue = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["value"]
```

Let me know if thats what you are after...

UPDATE:

Ok I think this should do what you are after. You should be able to use this in a static method without passing in any context object.

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current); 
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData());
var completeRoute = requestContext.RouteData.Route;
var justValue = requestContext.RouteData.Values["value"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i don't want get current route values within controller, i want get that from simple class. please see codes on my question. value should retrieve by GetSomeValue method.

Comment: How to get these values in global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

I used anthonyv's answer for my static class but the results were null. The following worked for me (similar to how to access Session objects in a static class).

```
var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var action = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Comment: How to get these values in global.asax?

Comment: This post is coming back to life after 6 years!

Answer (score 0):

Global would be nice, but so far I've only seen it within Controller:

```
Namespace Controllers
  Public Class HomeController
    Inherits BaseController
      Dim routeValues = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
      Dim actionName As String
      Dim controllerName As String

      Public Function Index(id As String) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim y As Integer = 5
            Dim z As Integer = y / x
        Catch ex As Exception
            If routeValues IsNot Nothing Then
                If routeValues.ContainsKey("action") Then
                    actionName = routeValues("action").ToString()
                End If
                If routeValues.ContainsKey("controller") Then
                    controllerName = routeValues("controller").ToString()
                End If
            End If

            Log.LogError(ex, controllerName, actionName)
        End Try
```